# How to inform Maven/JVM options for S2I build in OpenShift3

Tags: maven, docker, github, openshift, openshift-client-tools

OpenShift3 allows to build a container from a Github repository using the concept of "S2I - Source to Image".

For example:

```
oc new-app codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos~https://github.com/cbelleza/spring-boot-samples.git --context-dir=spring-boot-basewebapp
```

Is there any way to inform what Maven goals should be executed during that building?

How can I set what JVM parameters my application needs to be started such as -DXbootclasspath:, -Dfile.encoding, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the specific S2I builder you are using is implemented. You need to find where the provider of that S2I builder has their code and documentation.

Seems you can find documentation for it at:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos/

and their repo for it is at:

- https://github.com/codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos

Comment: Could you give me any example how to pass the parameters to Maven? Tks!

Comment: The documentation tells you what environment variable you need to set to pass arguments to Maven. What aspect of that are you having a problem with?

Comment: I mean using directly the OC command in Openshift3, and without creating a custom Dockerfile

Comment: The command for setting environment variables against a build is ``oc setenv bc/buildconfigname``. Run ``oc setenv --help`` for more details.